Treatment of expl3 variables - registers versus macros
In expl3 some variables are implemented as TeX registers (dim, skip, muskip, int) while others are implemented as macros (tl, str, clist, fp, bitset, etc.)
(Relevant: interface3.pdf section "Terminological inexactitude".)
My question is whether programmers should treat expl3 variables differently depending on whether they are internally implemented as a register or a macro.
Is it best practice to ignore this distinction?
It seems like that is part of the idea behind V- and v-type arguments because they will get the content of an expl3 variable regardless of whether it is implemented as a TeX register or a macro.
I provide 2 examples.
Example 1:
The e-type argument will expand everything exhaustively (this replaces the deprecated x-type argument)---this includes TeX macros and the expl3 variables that are implemented as macros, but not the expl3 variables that are TeX registers.
For efficiency, since TeX registers do not expand inside an e-type argument, a programmer could prevent the expansion of an expl3 variable  (via \exp_not:N', \exp_not:n, etc. ) for those implemented as macros, but not for those implemented as TeX registers.
But this may be syntactically inconsistent.
Would it be better to (a) always explicitly prevent the expansion of an expl3 variable inside an e-type argument or (b) only prevent the expansion of the expl3 variables that are implemented as macros?
Example 2:
When testing the equality of two expl3 variables implemented as macros, a programmer could use \token_if_eq_meaning:NNTF.
For example, a programmer could test floating point equality using
\fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp { 1 }
\token_if_eq_meaning:NNTF \l_tmpa_fp \c_one_fp {<TRUE>} {<FALSE>}

This is much faster than:
\fp_compare:nNnTF \l_tmpa_fp = \c_one_fp {<TRUE>} {<FALSE>}

But it may be syntactically inconsistent with the dim and int comparison tests.
A similar issue has been bought up here:
https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/1499
Or with sequences:
\seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 }
\seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 }
\token_if_eq_meaning:NNTF \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpb_seq {<TRUE>} {<FALSE>}

Of course, this would be much faster than testing whether each sequence has the same number of items and testing the equality of each item with the same index.
Would it be better to (a) use the faster \token_if_eq_meaning:NNTF comparison test or (b) use the slower, but perhaps more syntactically consistent comparison method?
The MWE below just provides some code examples:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{parskip}%looks nicer
\begin{document}
% \ExplSyntax shouldn't be used at the document level. This is just for demonstration.
\ExplSyntaxOn
\fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp { 1 }
\token_if_eq_meaning:NNTF \l_tmpa_fp \c_one_fp {<TRUE>} {<FALSE>}
\par
\fp_compare:nNnTF \l_tmpa_fp = \c_one_fp {<TRUE>} {<FALSE>}
\par
\fp_compare:nNnTF \l_tmpa_fp = \c_pi_fp {<TRUE>} {<FALSE>}
\par
\seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 }
\seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 }
\token_if_eq_meaning:NNTF \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpb_seq {<TRUE>} {<FALSE>}
\par
\seq_put_right:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { 6 }
\token_if_eq_meaning:NNTF \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpb_seq {<TRUE>} {<FALSE>}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}


First code as if speed is not important and in reality gaining a millionth of a second in a comparison is immaterial at  document level where fonts, images and tikz-like code dominates the compilation speed.  In edge cases where speed is important as you have thousands of usages of the same command. Then I would  use core TeX.  Readability of the code is more important. Like in your comparison for for the fp example, using fp_compare is preferable, it will also be indexed correctly, which might be useful during development.

The implementation detail of expl3 is not guaranteed, rather the API documentation describes the design behaviour. As such, programmers should not write code which is predicated on particular aspects of the implementation.
For example, the prop data type has been implemented a few different ways: many years ago it relied on toks, we switched to macros and we have recently expanded the implementation to allow two distinct underlying structures (both macro-based but distinct). The API documentation still works, as the official accessors, etc., are reliable.
In terms of variables, it is documented that tl expand, so this can be relied upon (with hindsight, perhaps an implementation as protected macros would have been better). Other variables are not documented as doing this, but as none are documented as protected functions, I would use \exp_not:N routinely when a variable appears in an e- (or x-) type context.
Whilst \cs_if_eq:NN(TF) or \token_if_eq_meaning:NN(TF) can be used to compare two tokens, in general for variable comparison I would use the appropriate \<type>_if_eq:NN(TF) function. This avoids relying on the implementation at all, and is also clearer - note that depending on the underlying implementation, this may well be equivalent to \cs_if_eq:NN(TF) anyway.
There is of course a place to consider performance - most obviously in the implementation of expl3 itself but also in other places. However, other than the tightest of loops, it is better not to worry about implementation detail; A more tricky consideration is for example when to use 'dedicated' structured storage over say a prop - see for example how I store units and numbers in siunitx. (Units are in a prop, numbers in a dedicated structure held in a tl.)
One thing that is definitely slow is the regex module: delimited functions will always be 1000s of times faster where they are appropriate.

Even a token by token loop is faster than regex if the applied test function to the individual tokens isn't absolutely horrible :) regex is a great module for q&d stuff though, or for really complicated stuff. Also, when tl was first implemented there was no \protected (though I agree, it would be nice to have consistent expansion behaviour for all variables and explicit accessors if one needs expansion).

@Skillmon Sure, but when we revised from tlp to tl, using \edef\foo{\unexpanded{...}, we could have used \protected: I missed that at the time

But the same behaviour as the current tl was already possible in pre-e-TeX, though a bit more cumbersome, I thought that had been used before. Sorry.

@Skillmon Performance was the issue - the current approach is only very slightly slower than using a 'raw' macro, whereas going via a toks would more-or-less double the time

The examples are flawed, sorry. With \fp_compare:nNnTF you compare two fp-expressions, not just two fp-variables.
A fast test on whether two fp-variables are equal could be done with \token_if_eq_meaning:NNTF, and called \fp_if_eq:NNTF; but how useful would it be? Generally, fp-variables are compared for “size”, equality only being a possible case.
Adding the example for sequences, your code should have
\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \usertwothreefour_fp_if_eq_variables:NN { p,T,F,TF }
 {
  \token_if_eq_meaning:NNTF #1 #2 { \prg_return_true: } { \prg_return_false: }
 }
\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \usertwothreefour_seq_if_eq:NN { p,T,F,TF }
 {
  \token_if_eq_meaning:NNTF #1 #2 { \prg_return_true: } { \prg_return_false: }
 }

and use
\usertwothreefour_fp_if_eq_variables:NN \l_tmpa_fp \l_tmpb_fp { true } { false }

\usertwothreefour_seq_if_eq:NNTF \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpb_seq { true } { false }

This is just a skeleton, of course: a real test should also check whether the two tokens that follow are fp-variables or sequences to begin with. This can be easily done. But as it requires accessing the internal structure, it would be better to ask the team to add the feature.
Anything that's based on the low level implementation should be hidden to the programmer. Even if your feature request is not accepted, you should still continue to use \usertwothreefour_seq_if_eq:NNTF, so you can just change its implementation in case the low level implementation of sequences changes.

In section "1.1 Naming functions and variables", on page 2 of interface3.pdf, released 2024‑03‑14, you learn about variables:

V and v
These mean value of variable. The V and v specifiers are used to get the content of a variable without needing to worry about the underlying TeX structure containing the data. A V argument will be a single token (similar to N), for example \foo:V \MyVariable; on the other hand, using v a csname is constructed first, and then the value is recovered, for example \foo:v {MyVariable}.

At the end of that section, on page 4 of interface3.pdf, you learn:

Variables are named in a similar manner to functions, but begin with a single letter to define the type of variable:









c
Constant: global parameters whose value should not be changed.


g
Parameters whose value should only be set globally.


l
Parameters whose value should only be set locally.



Each variable name is then build up in a similar way to that of a function, typically starting with the module1 name and then a descriptive part. Variables end with a short identifier to show the variable type:









bitset
a set of bits (a string made up of a series of 0 and 1 tokens that are accessed by position).


clist
Comma separated list.


dim
"Rigid" lengths.


fp
Floating‑point values;


int
Integer‑valued count register.


muskip
"Rubber" lengths for use in mathematics.


skip
"Rubber" lengths.


str
String variables: contain character data.


tl
Token list variables: placeholder for a token list.



Applying V‑type or v‑type expansion to variables of one of the above types is supported, while it is not supported for the following variable types:









bool
Either true or false.


box
Box register.


coffin
A "box with handles"—a higher‑level data type for carrying out box alignment operations.


flag
Non‑negative integer that can be incremented expandably.


fparray
Fixed‑size array of floating point values.


intarray
Fixed‑size array of integers.


ior⁠/​iow
An input or output stream, for reading from or writing to, respectively.


prop
Property list: analogue of dictionary or associative arrays in other languages.


regex
Regular expression.


seq
"Sequence": a data‑type used to implement lists (with access at both ends) and stacks.



1The module names are not used in case of generic scratch registers defined in the data type modules, e.g., the int module contains some scratch variables called \l_tmpa_int, \l_tmpb_int, and so on. In such a case adding the module name up front to denote the module and in the back to indicate the type, as in \l_int_tmpa_int would be very unreadable.

In section "5.3 Introducing the variants", on page 34 of interface3.pdf, you find:

The V type returns the value of a register, which can be one of tl, clist, int, skip, dim, muskip, or built‑in TeX registers. The v type is the same except it first creates a control sequence out of its argument before returning the value.

Some nitpicking‑remarks of the author of the initial release of this answer:

Unlike in section 1.1, in section 5.3 the types bitset, fp and str are not mentioned extra in the list of those types where V‑type‑expansion⁠/​v‑type‑expansion is supported. Maybe the information is contradictory. Maybe the information is not contradictory but these types are implemented in terms of built‑in TeX registers so that mentioning them extra is obsolete in section 5.3. Who knows without looking at implementation‑details provided in source3.pdf? Will newcomers understand these?
The meanings of terms also depend on the context in which they are used. (Otherwise, e.g., concepts like operator‑overloading would in any case imply ambiguity.) The meaning of the term "type of variable" seems not really clarified in the context of LaTeX3‑variables:
On the one hand you are advised to "begin with a single letter" (c or g or l) "to define the type of variable".
[Side question: Do you really define something this way? Do you really define the type of a variable this way? Or do you probably just specify an already introduced type while declaring a variable? (As someone who is more inclined towards Immanuel Kant when it comes to the theory of definition, the author of the initial release of this answer is a bit at odds with the "theory of definition" that one comes across in TeX jargon.) ]
On the other hand you are told that "Variables end with a short identifier to show the variable type".
So what exactly is "the" variable type? Does that single letter (c or g or l) alone denote the "type" of a variable? Is the "type" of a variable denoted by the bitset⁠/​clist⁠/​dim⁠/​fp⁠/​int⁠/​muskip⁠/​skip⁠/​str⁠/​tl⁠/​bool⁠/​box⁠/​coffin⁠/​flag⁠/​fparray⁠/​intarray⁠/​ior⁠/​iow⁠/​prop⁠/​regex⁠/​seq-thingie? Do you need a mixture of both for determining⁠/​denoting the "type" of a variable?
You find the term "rubber length". In the times when the author of the initial release of this answer naively trustingly started learning and using LaTeX—in his first semester at university he was urged to both productively use and learn LaTeX at the same time, which in his humble opinion is not a good way of approaching matters; first learn, then use productively—, after having seen that term in some introduction that was misleading also in some other ways, he used the term "rubber length" once or twice when asking a question at the newsgroup comp.text.tex. Back then usage of the term "rubber length" was criticized by longstanding regulars of the newsgroup who are to be considered luminaries in the field of TeX‑programming and TeX‑jargon. And that criticism is justified: "rubber length" is not official TeX terminology in the sense of being terminology that is introduced and explained in the TeXbook of Donald E. Knuth. To the author of the initial release of this answer a rubber is a more or less flexible piece of gum used for erasing things written with a pencil or a pen from a piece of paper and used up over time. The concept of so‑called "glue" in TeX is not that much about erasing things. It also is not that much about flexibility. It is about describing criteria for "fixating" things⁠/​for "fixating" horizontal and⁠/​or vertical distances in stages of producing boxes.
The term "use in mathematics" seems not clarified. The author of the initial release of this answer assumes that this term is about having TeX typeset things in some math mode. The name muskip indicates that this is about the spacing within math formulas and the concept of ⟨muglue⟩ introduced in the TeXbook of Donald E. Knuth.

After all, let's now focus on the question:

My question is whether programmers should treat expl3 variables differently depending on whether they are internally implemented as a register or a macro.

The author of the initial release of this answer tends to treat expl3 variables differently depending on whether they are or are not of a type where applying V‑type‑expansion⁠/​v‑type expansion is supported and whether macros \⁠⟨⁠type⁠⟩⁠_⁠use⁠:⁠N⁠/​\⁠⟨⁠type⁠⟩⁠_⁠use⁠:⁠c are available. Both V‑type or v‑type expansion and applying the corresponding \⁠⟨⁠type⁠⟩⁠_⁠use⁠:⁠N‑macro or \⁠⟨⁠type⁠⟩⁠_⁠use⁠:⁠c‑macro can be combined with a piece of code which in turn applies the desired expansion on the tokens forming the value of the variable in question.
In case you wish a control sequence which denotes a LaTeX3‑variable to be preserved as is throughout some expansion‑context, just use \exp_not:N (or probably \exp_not:c) or \exp_not:n. Be aware that the effect of \exp_not:N may differ from the effect of \exp_not:n in the context of f‑expansion.
See, e.g., the console‑output of
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_to_str:n { f }
\tl_new:N \l_my_tl
\tl_set:Nn \l_my_tl {Hello}
\tex_message:D{^^J\tl_to_str:f{\exp_not:n{\l_my_tl}}}
\tex_message:D{^^J\tl_to_str:f{\exp_not:N \l_my_tl}}
\stop

, which is:
Hello 
\l_my_tl 

In case of variable types where V‑type‑expansion⁠/​v‑type expansion is not supported and macros \⁠⟨⁠type⁠⟩⁠_⁠use⁠:⁠N⁠/​\⁠⟨⁠type⁠⟩⁠_⁠use⁠:⁠c are not available, this is due to the circumstance that variables of such types don't have a single value which could be considered "the value of that variable" but are used for storing several pieces of data. With such variable types it is recommended to use the  "official interface" provided for retrieving pieces of data that form components of the value of the variable. The recommendation to use the official interface is because internal implementation details with such data structures may be subject to changes.
The previous remarks about the handling of expansion in the context of retrieving the values of variables only makes sense with variables where related to the value expansion might be a relevant aspect.
E.g., with variables of types like box and coffin the values consist of material that is already typeset into boxes so that expansion is not that much an issue.

Apparently, documenting supporting a V-type argument for a seq variable was a "copy-paste mistake" and it was never actually supported. See the comments by Joseph Wright: https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/1466

@User23456234 Thanks for pointing this out. I removed my remarks about this from my answer.
